# send reaction on telegram channel post with python?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

is there any way to send a reaction to my telegram channel post with python
i checked API on tl.telethon.dev not get any hint about that

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SendReactionRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/send_reaction.html) in v1.25+:

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

result = await client(functions.messages.SendReactionRequest(
    peer='username',
    msg_id=42,
    reaction='❤️'
))
```